# Command line JavaScript occasionally not printing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

While I write javascript and I'm unsure of its behavior I like to run it through node's REPL shell to verify that it works as intended.

When I was testing a minified enclosed function I noticed some odd behavior with node: *Occasionally it doesn't output any value*.

[image: No output]

It doesn't "reliably" occur, though I find I can get it to occur the most often when I attempt to use 2 different expressions.

**Question:** *Why is this happening? Is this a common occurrence that I have just never come across before?*

Here are the code segments I used in the example:

```
var testObj = { val1: false, val2: false };

!function(){for(var a in testObj)if(testObj.hasOwnProperty(a)&&!a)return!0}();

(function(){for(var a in testObj){if(testObj.hasOwnProperty(a)&&!a)return !0;}return !1;})();
```

Notes:

1. I have seen both functions produce this bug.
2. I have seen both functions do this on the first evaluation before I alternated between the two.
3. I have not tested this with other functions: only ones searching through an object's properties.
4. I'm not interested in what the functions are doing, unless it is what causes node to "miss" the output

Node v6.10.0
Windows 10 x64

Comment: The two in the very middle that are wrapped in `()` when put back to back will have a problem because there's no `;` separating them, so the `()` wrapping the second one is interpreted as *calling* the result of the previous one. It should give you a *TypeError*

Comment: `var res = (function(){for(var a in testObj{if(testObj.hasOwnProperty(a)&&!a)return !0;}return !1;})();console.log(res);//false`

Comment: As to your code example, the second one always returns inside the `for` loop, so you'll never get more than one iteration. Writing code on a single line like that doesn't help matters. Don't know why the REPL misses an output.

Comment: @squint I didn't notice the missing ; at the end of those lines, but if I'm not mistaken, I don't believe that that would affect the output in node unless I evaluated them at the same time

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. They'd need to be within the same expression statement.